# What is ngModule in input field in form

Tags: angular, angularjs-ng-model

I'm new abount Angular and I read a lot of tutorial, Suppose to have this code :

```
 <input type="text" id="username" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="username" name="username" required>
```

I understand that `[(ngModel)]` can map the input field value with the variable username. Now look this code:

```
    <form ngNativeValidate (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()" #f="ngForm">
....
     <input type="text" id="username" class="form-control" ngModule name="username" required>
    </form>
```

What is the difference between `ngModule` and `[(ngModel)]` ?

Comment: ngModule is not a standard Angular directive. ngNativeValidate isn't either. So we have no idea. You're apparently using custom directives and the author of these directives broke the good practive of **not** using the ng prefix, since ng is normally reserved for directives provided by Angular itself.

Comment: @JBNizet and If I use ngModel (instead of [(ngModel)] without associate variable) because I want to check parameters?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 2nd part of code you share is wrong. It should be **`ngModel`** not **`ngModule`** with input .

`@NgModule` is an annotation of Angular which allows us to fetch bundle of code related components/services/pipes.